# Centering div with image in slider

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I used part of the wordpress theme of another developer and now this slider content is floating to top

I want to center content vertically and horizontally with padding on all sides `padding:100px;`

Someone can visit my site and help with centering this block? This is url of my [mywebsite](http://arnoldpiscel.com), please share some knowledge and hope I will solve this problem.

Comment: Please post specific parts of your code here, instead of linking to your website.

Comment: I really dont know what code to include to post there is 5 div blocks above img , for those how know css well its just 1 minute to udnerstand what happens , but maybe this css of first div will help.. `.solofolio-cyclereact-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through your code, (thank god for Inspect Element on Google Chrome!) and it seems you have the header inside the body of the code, try moving the page header above the body in your html. I have found this to work for me in some cases.

Also next time try adding code relevant to the question to your OP, will help get faster and better answers

EDIT: You can centre it horizontally by changing the left and right tags in the css:

```
.//div class here {
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

EDIT 2: Try this, im not sure if it will work but its worth a show:

```
.//div class here {
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
}
```

Comment: thankss, but its the same I moved <body> below header and, the same... I dont knwo how to explain I want one wordpress slider as a gallery for pages and I writed for wordpress (index,header,footer,etc) and slider part got from one free theme , so now i need this slider center with -100px on the sides to work perfect with this theme I writed ...

Comment: @user3852799 Please reword that comment, i believe you want to centre the image slideshow horizontally and vertically, i have edited OP/Answer to include this now

Comment: @user3852799 No problem! Up Vote if you haven't already! (You really should be bale to see who up voted on this)

Comment: Already accepted your answer and upped, thanks one more time ^_^ Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the steps explained on this site: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/. You will most likely want to apply this to:

```
.image img
```

which is the CSS selector for the div with a class of image containing an image tag. This may be too general though and I actually recommend giving your image an ID and targeting that.